# Using the ImportXML function on Google Sheets to get the publication date of web pages

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets

I've been trying to work out a method using Google Sheets to return a publication date for news articles on websites. Some pages don't make this obvious or don't mention a publication date at all, but in the page source there is often a node like:

```
<meta content="2018-10-16T00:03:35+0100" itemprop="datePublished" />
```

So I've come up with a function like this:

```
=ImportXml(A19, "//meta[@itemprop='datePublished']/@content")
```

for a URL in cell A19, which will return the content if the node is using that syntax.

However on other pages, it won't be precisely that - the syntax will be something like this and Google Sheets returns the error "Imported content is empty":

```
<meta property ="article:published_time" content="2018-10-16T00:03:35+0100" />.
```

Seems that the relevant nodes in the source code would all contain the word "published" - is there a way to build my query so that it returns content from any node containing the word "published"?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Xpath query:

```
//meta[@*[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'published')]]/@content
```

It searches for any attribute containing "published" as a sub-string, with case insensitive match.

I tested it on this string:

```
<meta content="2018-10-16T00:03:35+0100" anyprop="datepublishedhelloworld" />
```

and it returned this result:

```
Attribute='content=2018-10-16T00:03:35+0100'
```

Using this tool https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: Let me know it this works in Google sheets as expected.

Comment: This does work much better, thanks! Returning fewer "Imported content is empty" errors and looking into the sites which return that, it seems there is no publication date available in the source anyway. Some sites returned the error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in [cell below]" as there were multiple instances of nodes with "published" on that site giving duplicate results, but that's solved with the index function:
=index(ImportXml(A8, "//meta[@*[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'published')]]/@content"),1)

Comment: OK great. I did not test in sheets, but looks like you found a good solution.